# Custom ExtJS Toggle Editor

Tags: extjs

I have editor grid having column having true and false. true is displayed using some green flag icon and false using red flag icon. I want a custom editor such that when user clicks on flag instead of checkbox, it should directly turn to red flag and vice versa.

Comment: Have a look into checkcolumn.

Comment: Thanks Alexander but I don't want to display a checkbox. Though it is Boolean field, but image of green flag is displayed as true and image of red flag for false. Clicking on image should toggle the value of the column

Comment: You can change the CSS really easily. You did the flags with CSS yourself, I guess - it should only be required to adapt it slightly for a checkboxcolumn. Can't say more than that if you don't show your code and what you already tried. Best would be if you made a fiddle with two columns - one old with the flags, one new with the checkcolumn, try how far you get with adapting CSS and post the result for us to assist.

Comment: It worked using actionColumn. Thank you.